# "If" in a trigger comparing two columns from 2 different tables- error

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sql-update, oracle-apex

Im trying to create a trigger when updating table 'test' to make sure a value in a column is not greater than another one from a different table. But I get this error on Oracle Apex: **ORA-24344: success with compilation error**

'test' is a table and 'chestionar' is a second one, so I want to launch that error when I insert a value in 'punctaj' which is greater than the 'punctaj_max'. And the id of the both tables must be the same . What should I modify?

here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger trg_a
BEFORE UPDATE on test 
begin
if test.punctaj > chestionar.punctaj_max and test.id=chestionar.id then 
 raise_application_error(234,'error, the value is grater than maximum of that id');
end if;
end;
```

Comment: *`if test.punctaj > chestionar.punctaj_max`* What do you think, from which rows of the `test` and `chestionar` tables should the server take values? Use SELECT INTO then check the output.

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic you want is:

```
create or replace trigger trg_a
before update on test
for each row
declare 
    p_punctaj_max chestionar.punctaj_max%type;
begin
    select punctaj_max into p_punctaj_max from chestionar c where c.id = :new.id;
    if :new.punctaj > p_punctaj_max then 
        raise_application_error(234, 'error, the value is grater than maximum of that id');
    end if;
end;
/
```

The idea is to recover the value of `punctaj_max` in table `chestionar` for the  `id` of the row that is being updated in `test` (note that this implicitely assumes that there cannot be multiple matching rows in `chestionar`). We can then compare that to the value being updated, and raise the error if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have three (I think) issue in your code:

- You should apply trigger at time of insert also.
- you need to query the table chestionar and then compare the value.
- the error number in raise_application_error should be negative and between -20999 and -20000.

So, I would rewrite your code as follows:

```
create or replace trigger trg_a
before update or insert on test
for each row
declare 
    lv_cnt number := 0;
begin
    select count(1) into lv_cnt 
      from chestionar c 
     where c.id = :new.id
       and :new.punctaj > c.punctaj_max;

    if lv_cnt > 0 then 
        raise_application_error(-20234, 'error, the value is grater than maximum of that id');
    end if;
end;
/
```